# How to Make a remind when my IM app in backgroud

Tags: ios, notifications

I can't receive remind when my iOS IM App in background while receive new message
,what should I do? I am tried to monitor the message arrive method,And use the NSLocalNotification to show a remind. But when My App in background ,the method no work.  So.How to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your app cant run while in the background. You should use APNs to do it.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: PS. [apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: My App use LeanCloud to do IM,  LeanCloud's server doesn't send a push notification when receive messages,So I can't use the remote notification,and try to use the NSLocalNotification

Comment: Here is tutorial for APNs from LeanCloud.cn [https://leancloud.cn/docs/ios_push_guide.html](https://leancloud.cn/docs/ios_push_guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

i once met the same problem.cause socket connection is also alive when app enter background.

so i solved like this:

1. disconnect to IM server when my app enter background,so IM server would send remote notification through APNs.
2. connect to IM server when my app enter foreground,so IM server would send message through socket connection.